# Как прикрепить к рубрике уникальную иконку и вывести ее в записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 14);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<div class="span3">
    <div class="video">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы к постам, которые относятся к рубрикам #38 и #32 добавить иконку такую, а к остальным другую?

Answer (score 2):

Для каждой отдельной страницы, категории и записи WordPress генерирует свои уникальные классы. Используя их, можете написать примерно такой CSS:

```
.archive.category-38 .article ..добавьте свой код.. {
background: ...ваш код...;
}
```

Либо приведите пример конкретной части кода, для наглядности.
Надеюсь, это вам поможет.